# TSQL- Using CASE in WHERE clause with a < or = sign

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to select the IDs based on period and type of account.Each account type would have a different period. I tried the following code but it didnt like the < operator or any other operators. I cannot use a temp table due to system limitation.  There are at least 6 types of accounts.
I searched for different solutions but I didnt find anything . Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

```
DECLARE @Inputperiod as INT 
DECLARE @Start as INT
DECLARE @Enddate as INT

    SET @Inputperdiod ='2009';
    SET @Start=@Inputperiod-1;
    SET @Enddate=@Inputperiod +1;

        SELECT ID, Period, Type 
        FROM
        TABLE1

        WHERE 

        Period= CASE

        WHEN Type='ASSET' THEN Period < @inputperiod 
        WHEN Type='Liability' THEN Period BETWEEN @start AND @enddate
        END
```

Comment: Didn't like it how?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - using CASE in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606019/sql-server-using-case-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the case statement.  What you have in your THEN clause is what is returned by the CASE statement (like an if... then... statement).  The way you have it written, it returns a boolean.

Try this instead...

```
SELECT ID, Period, Type
FROM Table1
WHERE Type='ASSET' AND Period < @inputperiod
UNION
SELECT ID, Period, Type
FROM Table1
WHERE Type='Liability' AND Period BETWEEN @start AND @enddate
```

Comment: You would use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` as `DISTINCT` was not specified in the original query.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `CASE` to swap out arbitrary bits of the query. You would need to use

```
   SELECT ID, Period, Type 
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE (Type='ASSET' AND Period < @inputperiod ) 
    OR    (Type='Liability' AND Period BETWEEN @start AND @enddate)
```