# Using case within where clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TSQL- Using CASE in WHERE clause with a < or = sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757026/tsql-using-case-in-where-clause-with-a-or-sign)

How can I use this query in a SQL Server stored procedure?

```
@VAR1 VARCHAR(2),
AS

SELECT     
    *
FROM         
    TABLE1
WHERE     
    Colum1 = 1
    CASE WHEN @VAR1 = 'OK' THEN 
           AND Colum2 = @Var1
    ELSE
           AND Colum2 IN ('String1','String2')
    END
```

Thank you very much already now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin Smith already pointed out in his comment, you can't use `CASE` to swap out `WHERE` clauses.

What you can do is this:

```
SELECT     
    *
FROM         
    TABLE1
WHERE     
    Colum1 = 1
    AND 
    (
        (@VAR1 = 'OK' and Colum2 = @VAR1)
        OR
        (@VAR1 <> 'OK' and Colum2 IN ('String1','String2'))
    )
```

Comment: yes, it works very well. thak you very much.